# Что не так с MySQL

Tags: mysql

Имею такую таблицу заказов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При каждом посещении сайта, выполняется такой запрос:

```
$delete = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM `Tickets` WHERE `death` >= ? AND `user` = ?;');
$delete -> execute(array(time(),$name));
```

Несмотря на то что текущее время не больше времени смерти, код все-равно удаляет заказ.

Почему? Видимо что-то не так с запросом?

Comment: ну так в запросе же и написано удалить записи у которой death больше текущего времени, что то же самое что и "текущее время не больше времени смерти"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Несмотря на то что текущее время не больше времени смерти

```
Несмотря на то что time() не больше `death`
Несмотря на то что time() <= `death`
Несмотря на то что `death` >= time()
```

Запрос делает то, что сказано. А что сказано не то, что хотелось - это не его вина...

Comment: Видимо мне не хватает мозгов.. Подскажите как тогда удалять строки, в которых наступила дата смерти?

Comment: @W_0rld Наступила - это значит "меньше текущего времени" просто поменяйте условие на противоположное

Comment: А, точно. Дата смерти же не может быть больше текущего времени.